# Browserify v16.2.3 includes both react development and production while building

Tags: reactjs, browserify

I am using browserify v16.3.2 to build react v16 app. In the created `bundle.js`, I found that both react.development and react.production.min are there, as well as react-dom

I want to set NODE_ENV, followed [React official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#browserify), but no effect.

Then I tried below command, it still conatins all react.development, react.production.min, react-dom.development and react-dom.production.min

```
NODE_ENV=production browserify -t [ babelify --ignore [ node_modules ] --compact --presets [ @babel/react @babel/env ] --plugins [ @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties ] ] main.js -o bundle.js
```

Here is my `main.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Hello World</p>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Expected:**

Either react.development or react.production.min is contained, depends on NODE_ENV. Same for react-dom

**Actual:**

All react.development, react.production.min, react-dom.development and react-dom.production.min are there